# What are the rules of Ziro?

Tags: ziro

There are die which the player slides and then combines: some are blue, some are red, each has a particular figure written on one face. Sometimes the combination gives a sum, sometimes a difference, and the resulting dice is of one of the two possible die colors.

I don't understand the rules of the indie puzzle game Ziro. I am playing a bit too randomly for the game to be enjoyable. Has someone figured out the deterministic rules of this game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color is irrelevant. Let us say we have two die (A and B). The result is:

- no dice if A is equal to B,
- A+B if the result is less than or equal to nine.
- |A-B| otherwise.